# Can I guarantee that one index in a vector can be made larger than any other from a given set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of vectors of length $N$ that I'm going to be adding or subtracting in various combinations. My goal is to prove that for each index in the resulting vector, there exists some combination of adding or subtracting the vectors that will make the value at that index have a value larger than any other index. I don't necessarily need to know what the solution is, just that one exists.

e.g. if I have two vectors

$$v_1 = (1, 0)$$
$$v_2 = (0, 1)$$

then I know trivially that I can maximize the first position with $v_1-v_2$ and the second with $v_2 - v_1$.

One obviously necessary condition is that to have index $i$ large, there must be at least one vector where that index is non-zero. A reasonable first guess would be add up all the vectors with a positive number in that position and subtract the rest, but that doesn't always work, e.g. if

$$v_1 = (2, 1)$$
$$v_2 = (1, 2)$$

then $v_1 + v_2$ has the two elements tied at $(3, 3)$. But a solution does exist: $v_1 - v_2 = (1, -1)$ has the first element the largest, and $v_2 - v_1 = (-1, 1)$ has the 2nd element largest.

I've taken enough math in my day that I recognize that "does such a solution exist" (for a given set of vectors) is probably answerable, but it's been long enough that I don't remember how to go about actually answer it. I imagine it'll have something to do with determinants or eigenvalues or something. Any pointers on how to solve this, or under what conditions the answer to this question will be "yes"? I'm also interested if the question changes significantly if I allow some vectors to be left out of the sum. Thanks.